# amazon-ecs-agent is always restarting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, amazon-ecs

I have an autoscaling group on amazon, that spawns server instances.

My aws-cli config is:

```
[default]
s3 =
    signature_version = s3v4
    addressing_style = path
region = eu-central-1
```

My ecs-agent config gets read from s3 with aws-cli at instance bootup and is as follows:

```
ECS_CLUSTER=cluster-mongodb
ECS_ENGINE_AUTH_TYPE=dockercfg
ECS_ENGINE_AUTH_DATA={"domain.com":{"auth":"bsaewfgvewgf23g9hv3","email":""}}
```

Sadly the ecs-agent on the spawned instance is always restarting after 10 secs, instead of registering to the cluster "cluster-mongodb".

The error log is here:

```
2016-02-05T14:40:47Z [INFO] Starting Agent: Amazon ECS Agent - v1.7.1 (007985c)
2016-02-05T14:40:47Z [INFO] Loading configuration
2016-02-05T14:40:47Z [INFO] Checkpointing is enabled. Attempting to load state
2016-02-05T14:40:47Z [INFO] Loading state! module="statemanager"
2016-02-05T14:40:47Z [INFO] Detected Docker versions [1.17 1.18 1.19 1.20]
2016-02-05T14:40:47Z [INFO] Registering Instance with ECS
2016-02-05T14:41:07Z [ERROR] Could not register module="api client" err="RequestError: send request failed
caused by: Post https://ecs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection"
2016-02-05T14:41:07Z [ERROR] Error registering: RequestError: send request failed
caused by: Post https://ecs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection
```

Someone has seen this before?
Is this maybe related to messed up security groups/LB config?

Thanks in advance

[EDIT] found the solution:

check, if the subnet is registered to the right route table (vpc -> route tables). in my case it was the wrong one.

Additionally my instances needed a public IP assigned by the launch configuration of the Autoscaling group, but that was special to my setup.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That message indicates your instance cannot do an HTTPS POST to the `ecs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com` endpoint.

Make sure your security groups and/or VPC configuration allows outbound HTTPS to your [ECS endpoint](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#ecs_region).

You can confirm endpoint connectivity from the instance to the endpoint the command line:

```
curl https://ecs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
```

That should return a message similar to the following:

```
<MissingAuthenticationTokenException>
  <Message>Missing Authentication Token</Message>
</MissingAuthenticationTokenException>
```

Comment: yes, i cant reach ecs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com from the instance, i get a timeout. the VPC ACLs are completely open though, all traffic allowed. same goes for the security group of the autoscaling group and the instance. where else can i search?

Comment: Are you using iptables/local firewall to restrict outgoing from the instance? Can you access say https://www.google.com from the local instance? Does the instance itself have a security group? What are the outbound rules there?

Comment: well, the instances have a public ip, but cant reach the internet. if i manually attach an elastic ip to the instance, they can. but since the instance is started from autoscaling, i need another solution for the problem. you have an idea?

Comment: found it: the subnet was not registered to the right route table (vpc -> route tables)

Comment: Had the same issue, I realized I had HTTP and not HTTPS open on my security groups

Comment: I had to add the ECS endpoint to the VPC.

Answer (score 0):

Use a NAT instance and let the internet flow through that for private VM inside your VPC.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, ecs agent need internet access to connect with ecs endpoint i.e. https://ecs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com.

Either ECS instance have pubic IP or they are using NAT instance/Gateway for public access.

see link https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=781868 for more details